# sending variable commands in vim-slime

Tags: command-line, external-command, tmux

I am relatively new to vim and have started using the [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) plugin. One thing I use it for is to run python scripts, for example

```
:SlimeSend1 python ~/myPythonFile.py
```

I now would like to automate the command above. More specifically, I would like to map the command above to a keystroke, but for whatever python file I happen to be working with. Using F5 as my example keystroke, I am looking for something like

```
:map <F5> SlimeSend1 python expand('%:p')<CR>
```

The command above doesn't work because it sends the literal string "python expand('%:p')". As a note, I have gone through vim-slime's documentation, but still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you can always get around this kind of problem by using `:execute` and building the command you want to run as a string:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :execute 'SlimeSend1 python' expand('%:p')<CR>
```

See `:help :execute` for more details.

Comment: Note the first suggestion in the answer from @Mass would also work. The command would be `:nnoremap <F5> :SlimeSend1 python <c-r>%<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, `:SlimeSend1` sends its arguments literally, as a single string.  You could type `CTRL+R` to insert the `%` register, which is the current filename:

```
:SlimeSend1 python <c-r>%
```

You could use `SlimeSend0` instead which accepts an expression.

```
:SlimeSend0 'python '.expand('%:p')
```

This command is a bit unwieldy.  You can use a wrapper command;

```
let s:flags = '<\=\%(:[p8~.htre]\|:g\=s\(.\).\{-\}\1.\{-\}\1\)*'
let s:expandable = '\\*\%(<\w\+>\|%\|#\d*\)' . s:flags
function! s:expand(string) abort
  let slashes = len(matchstr(a:string, '^\%(\\\\\)*'))
  sandbox let v = repeat('\', slashes/2) . expand(a:string[slashes : -1])
  return v
endfunction
function! TExpand(string) abort
  return substitute(a:string, s:expandable,
          \ '\=s:expand(submatch(0))', 'g')
endfunction

command! -complete=shellcmd -bang -nargs=+ Send
      \ SlimeSend0 TExpand(<q-args>)
```

I stole the `TExpand` function from [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/blob/e83ac42fefa4bcf2b4197bec2b4d917e15225815/autoload/dispatch.vim#L42).  If you have Dispatch installed you can simply use:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -bang -nargs=+ Send
      \ SlimeSend0 dispatch#expand(<q-args>)
```

Then `:Send python %` will work as you expect.

Comment: Did you mean to write `s:expand` instead of `dispatch#expand`?

Comment: @Mass My original question may not have been clear enough, so I updated it. Your first suggestion would work. Your next suggestion (:SlimeSend0) will send but not evaluate the command (unlike :SlimeSend1 which will both send and evaluate the command). Your last suggestion also seems to send but not evaluate the command.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg no actually, `TExpand` is the same as `dispatch#expand` (I just copy and pasted it).  `s:expand()` expands a single "%" while dispatch#expand expands an entire string e.g. "python %", emulating the expansion of the `:! ` command.

Comment: @user447986 Ah, yes my second suggestion will not work within a mapping (see @Rich's answer), only interactively.  But my last suggestion would work I think; `nnoremap <f5> :Send python %<cr> `.